# Universal memcomputing machines (UMM)

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, turing-machines, computer-architecture

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0931) on memcomputing seems like a really big deal, but it doesn't seem to be particularly popular.  They prove that their UMM can solve NP problems in P, although they don't claim P = NP.  [In their next paper](http://advances.sciencemag.org/content/1/6/e1500031.short), they go on to build a physical model of this UMM with moderate success. Does this mean P=NP?

Comment: Scott Aaronson talks about some of the issues with memcomputers' purported power on his blog [here](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2212). I don't know the field well enough to take this and make it a full answer, but perhaps someone else can.

Comment: I don't see an actual, answerable question, here. Popularity and "what do you think?" are matters of opinion and verifying the content of scientific papers is beyond the scope of the site. Could you edit your question to give something concrete and answerable?

Comment: @DylanSp Cool, thanks for the link to Scott's blog. That is the sort of things I have been trying to find.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think it just depends on how you interpret/answer my questions... For example, Is something popular, can be an objective question if answered with citations or some other metric.

Comment: @AlexanderTelfar "Does this paper have a lot of citations" is not a question about computer science so that angle doesn't fly, either.

Comment: I think the question here is what is the relationship between the memcomputing model and the P vs NP question, to which Yuval answered. An immediate followup question is what are the barriers on realizing such machines, to which Scott's blog provide several ideas.

Answer (score 5):

The authors suggest a new computation model that solves NP problems in polynomial time. Another such model has been known for a long time – non-deterministic Turing machines. They can also solve NP problems in polynomial time. In fact, one common definition of NP is the set of problems solvable by non-deterministic Turing machines in polynomial time.

If the authors succeed in realizing their machine physically (which is doubtful), then this shows that the "efficient Church–Turing thesis", which states that all physically realizable computation models can be simulated by a Turing machine using only polynomial overhead – is false. Another candidate for refuting this thesis is quantum computers, but they are conjectured not to be able to solve all NP problems in polynomial time.

Answer (score 3):

First, no this would not mean $P=NP$. That is a concept framed in the context of Turing machines. While it's been shown that UMMs are as expressive as Turing machines, it's not clear whether a physical realization of them would be Turing equivalent or simply *more* expressive than a Turing machine. If equivalence were to be proved (I don't think it's the case), then $P=NP$, otherwise a successful realization would have no implications for the question.

I can offer some context from my anecdotal experience about popularity: It's true that this wasn't particularly popular some time ago, but the idea is gaining traction, if you measure it by the attention it's getting in relevant fields. For instance, it's much easier for us to get NSF, DARPA, DOE funding now than 4-5 years ago. It seemed for a while that people would simply refer to Scott Aaronson's blogpost, which talked about a specific analog instantiation of UMMs, and then assume UMMs in general are a "non-serious" attempt at solving NP-complete problems in polynomial time. This ignores that the digital versions of UMMs are scalable (digital output doesn't require exponentially increasing precision to resolve), but most CS theorists would likely expect exponential complexity to still show up somewhere else (we disagree based on the physics involved and preliminary evidence is promising). To be fair to Scott, I don't think he was aware that digital versions existed. While the paper he criticized mentions it, it's easy to miss.

Right now, the idea is still not particularly popular among CS theorists (especially complexity theorists), who generally operate under the assumption that the extended Church-Turing thesis is true. We find less resistance from computer engineers, the unconventional computing community, and physicists. There are actually some good physical reasons to believe that UMMs are realizable (in a way that scales, see digital MemComputing machines, DMM).

For more information on the physical reasons we think this will be successful as well as empirical results for applications using simulated DMMs and more, see Di Ventra's textbook [MemComputing: Fundamentals and Applications](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780192845320.001.0001/oso-9780192845320).(Published by Oxford University Press, so rest assured that it's peer reviewed).

A useful analogy to understand the power of UMMs is to compare and contrast it with quantum computation, which also leverages physics to compute (primarily quantum entanglement as opposed to a UMMs strong coupling that emerges from memory-dynamics, those concepts are somewhat analogous). For a comparison of this kind, see [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.12031.pdf).